# R - count matches between characters of one string and another, no replacement

Tags: r

I have a keyword (e.g. 'green') and some text ("I do not like them Sam I Am!").

**I'd like to see how many of the characters in the keyword ('g', 'r', 'e', 'e', 'n') occur in the text (in any order).**

In this example the answer is 3 - the text doesn't have a G or R but has two Es and an N.

My problem arises where if a character in the text is matched with a character in the keyword, then it *can't* be used to match a different character in the keyword.

For example, if my keyword was 'greeen', the number of "matching characters" is still 3 (one N and two Es) because there are only two Es in the text, not 3 (to match the third E in the keyword).

How can I write this in R? This is just ticking something at the edge of my memory - I feel like it's a common problem but just worded differently (sort of like sampling with no replacement, but "matches with no replacement"?).

E.g.

```
keyword <- strsplit('greeen', '')[[1]]
text <- strsplit('idonotlikethemsamiam', '')[[1]]
# how many characters in keyword have matches in text,
# with no replacement?
# Attempt 1: sum(keyword %in% text)
# PROBLEM: returns 4 (all three Es match, but only two in text)
```

More examples of expected input/outputs (keyword, text, expected output):

- 'green', 'idonotlikethemsamiam', 3 (G, E, E)
- 'greeen', 'idonotlikethemsamiam', 3 (G, E, E)
- 'red', 'idonotlikethemsamiam', 2 (E and D)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The function pmatch() is great for this.  Though it would be instinctual to use length here, length has no na.rm option.  So to work around this nuisance, sum(!is.na()) is used.

```
keyword <- unlist(strsplit('greeen', ''))
text <- unlist(strsplit('idonotlikethemsamiam', ''))

sum(!is.na(pmatch(keyword, text)))

# [1] 3

keyword2 <- unlist(strsplit("red", ''))
sum(!is.na(pmatch(keyword2, text)))

# [1] 2
```

Comment: Aha! I spent ages trying `match` and `charmatch` and didn't notice that `pmatch` didn't allow duplicates (exactly what I wanted). Thanks a lot!

Comment: @mathematical.coffee pmatch does allow duplicates, but it's default is false.

Comment: yep, sorry, I mean "didn't notice that `pmatch` *had the option* to not allow duplicates"

Comment: `unlist` may avoid problems when there is a vector of character strings rather than subsetting `[[1]]`

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen Thanks, I was just using the example from the question for my data.  Editing now.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you are looking to find the UNIQUE components of your keyword?  Try:

```
keyword <- unique(strsplit('greeen','')[[1]])
```

Comment: no, I'm not. I'm trying to find the *number* of characters in the keyword that occur within the text, where if a character from the text matches one from the keyword, it cannot be used to match another character  from the keyword. My desired output is **numeric**, not a vector of characters.